# Equation of an ellipse with one focus at $(0,0)$

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

I have an ellipse with eccentricity $e_c$, semi-major axis and one focus is at $(0,0)$. [Here is my graph.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yczlriynp3)

So I am wondering, what is the equation of an ellipse in form $a(x+b)^2+y^2=r^2?$

**Note:** $b$ does not have to be a monomial or a constant. It can be of form $a+bx$ or $c(d+e)^f$, etc.

Comment: Try $x^2+y^2-e_c^2(l x+m y+ n)^2/(l^2+m^2)=0$ where $l x+m y+ n=0$ is the directrix.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question: giving a focus and eccentricity is not enough to fix an ellipse.